# Copy Control in C++

Tags: c++, constructor, copy-constructor

```
template <class Type> class Queue {


    Queue(): head(0), tail(0) {
        cout << "Queue--default constructor called" << endl;
    }

    Queue(const Queue &Q): head(0), tail(0) {
        cout << "Queue--copy constructor called" << endl;
        //...
    }

    Queue& operator=(const Queue&) {
        cout << "Queue--operator= called" << endl;
        //...
    }
    ~Queue() { //... }

private:
    QueueItem<Type> *head;         
    QueueItem<Type> *tail;         
};
```

I have defined a template class `Queue` and tried the codes below:

```
Queue<char*> cq;
Queue<char*> ccq(cq);   
Queue<char*> acq = cq;  
Queue<char*> acq2;
acq2 = cq;
```

and the **output** is:

```
Queue--default constructor called
Queue--copy constructor called
Queue--copy constructor called
Queue--default constructor called
Queue--operator= called
```

what confuse me is the code `Queue<char*> acq = cq;` has invoked the copy constructor `Queue--copy constructor called` but **not** the `default constructor and operator=` to be called.

Could any one help me?

Thank you for considering my question!

Comment: You're making a new Queue object based on an existing Queue object. Why would you expecting anything else than a copy constructor?

Comment: [Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_constructor#Definition) are some hints for you

Comment: @Gaminic you have to understand the confusion here. He writes the = and doesn't invoke the = operator. If he would write this as `Queue<char*> acq; acq=cq;` he would get what he describes, it's not intuitively obvious that declaring it in the same line is different. e.g. that `Queue<char*> acq=cq;` and `Queue<char*> acq(cq);` are the same thing.

Comment: @PeterT: I do understand the confusion; I was trying to make him see my point by thinking about it. If he can't answer the question, he'll understand. If he can answer the question, his reasoning will allow me to explain more precisely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is defined in the standard, it's in the section `Explicit initialization`

> 1
>   Explicit initialization
>   [class.expl.init]
>   An object of class type can be initialized with a parenthesized expression-list, where the expression-list
>   is construed as an argument list for a constructor that is called to initialize the object. Alternatively, a
>   single assignment-expression can be specified as an initializer using the = form of initialization. Either
>   direct-initialization semantics or copy-initialization semantics apply; see 8.5.

This is the case describing `single assignment-expression` and `copy-initialization semantics`.

Technically there's no difference between the two forms `ccq(cq)` and `acq = cq`, as you have already seen from the output.

Comment: There's actually a small difference (§ 8.5/13 "The form of initialization (using parentheses or =) is generally insignificant, but does matter when the initializer or the entity being initialized has a class type; see below."), but this is irrelevant here.

Answer (score 2):

This is called "copy initialization" and C++ standard requires that

```
Queue<char*> acq  = cq;
```

shall be equivalent to

```
Queue<char*> acq (cq);
```

No mistake here.